# Dynamic INSERT script in SQL

Tags: sql-server, insert, archive, procedure

Is there a way to create dynamic INSERT scripts from a stored procedure in SQL?

I was asked to create an archive functionality where it is supposed to select a date range and create INSERT statements of all the rows of that range and navigate through all the foreign keys generating cascade INSERT scripts for those "dependency" tables too.

Is this near possible? I was researching about this and couldn't find anything.

Comment: are the FK columns to generate dynamic as well ? or are known at generation time ? Anyway, you could generate the statement as a string from the selects (one insert per row in result) and then use sp_executesql to execute the generated string. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there a reason you _have_ to use dynamic sql? I think you can do this without it.

Comment: For example, if I'm selecting: 

`SELECT Id, Name, CountryId FROM Person WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2016-01-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-25 23:59:59'`

The generated script should be:

`INSERT INTO Country (Id, Name) VALUES(45, 'Italy')
INSERT INTO Country (Id, Name) VALUES(46, 'France')

INSERT INTO Person (Id, Name, CountryId) VALUES(34, John, 45)
INSERT INTO Person (Id, Name, CountryId) VALUES(35, Claudia, 46)
INSERT INTO Person (Id, Name, CountryId) VALUES(36, Andrew, 45)`

And so on for any FK found.

Comment: Possible? Deffinatly. Easy to write? Hell no. Easy to maintain? Hell no. Are there any 3rd party tools you can use that will archive the data for you? Absolutly. Is it worth the while to write your own? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do inserts from other tables dynamically, you could do this with combination of INSERT and SELECT statements.  I am not sure if this is what you are after.

E.g.:

```
 INSERT INTO Person_Archive(Id,Name, CountryId)
       SELECT Id, Name, CountryId FROM Person 
       WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2016-01-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-25 23:59:59'
```

This is the harder one.  You only want to add Countries that dont exist into the Archive.  Of course more ways to skin a cat here, this is just articulating the approach.

```
INSERT INTO Country_Archive(Id, Name)  -- INSERT INTO THE archive
SELECT Country.CountryId, Country.Name FROM Person  -- SELECT rows
JOIN Country ON CountryID.Id = Person.CountryId -- Join on Country to get Country Name
WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2016-01-25  00:00:00' AND '2016-12-25 23:59:59'
-- Criteria for query
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country_Archive WHERE Country_Archive.Id = Person.CountryID) = 0)
-- This checks to see if CountryId hasn't already been added
GROUP BY Country.CountryId, Country.Name  -- This get unique records only, i.e. if multiple users have same country.
```